# How do I make my desktop PC boot up from a USB keyboard?

Tags: windows-10, bios

The power button on my desktop PC is wearing out.

I'd like to use my keyboard to power-on my PC from a complete shutdown.

I'm running a Dell XPS 8700, running Windows 10, and which runs Aptio Setup Utility when I boot into the BIOS.

I can't find any option to boot up from USB keyboard in Aptio Setup Utility, or in Windows 10.

Where should I be looking?

Answer (score 1):

I found that you may be able to go into your BIOS and there may be a "Power on by Keyboard" or something along those lines, potentially in a "Power management setup" folder. For the XPS 8700, this may be in the "Boot" or "Power" folder.

If you need help accessing the BIOS, here's the instructions from the [User's Manual](https://dl.dell.com/manuals/all-products/esuprt_desktop/esuprt_xps_desktop/xps-8700_owner%27s%20manual_en-us.pdf):

1 If you are booting from a USB device, connect the USB device to a USB port.

2 Turn on (or restart) your computer.

3 When F2 Setup, F12 Boot Options appears in the lower-right corner of the
screen, press .

NOTE: If you wait too long and the operating system logo appears, continue to
wait until you see the operating system’s desktop. Then shut down your
computer and try again.

<strike>I also found an option by going to Device Manager --> Keyboards and selecting the driver(s) --> Properties there is a checklist option to allow it to wake the keyboard. You may need to update the driver(s) if it isn't working.</strike>

The above only works for sleep mode.

Alternatively, you may be able to replace the power button. Instructions are in page 59 of the User's Manual that is linked. I think you should get this done eventually for the reasons mentioned by the other answerer John.

Good luck!

Comment: I mentioned in the original post that I've already booted into the BIOS and can't find the option, so I'm looking for more specific help. I should've been clearer, sorry. I know I can replace the button easily, I was just going to save myself $15 ordering a replacement. The computer is located under a desk, and most of my guests have difficulty finding the power button anyway, as it's not located on the front of the machine. Keyboard booting would be preferable.

Comment: Hey! I also found an option by going to Device Manager --> Keyboards and selecting the driver(s) --> Properties there is a checklist option to allow it to wake the keyboard. You may need to update the driver(s) if it isn't working.

Comment: That wakes it from sleep, not boots it from shutdown. Windows itself can't control what boots up the computer, because when the computer is shut down, Windows isn't running. The BIOS is kinda like a mini operating system that runs on the motherboard and is used to prepare the hardware for starting Windows or other operating systems. The BIOS is what configures what can boot up the hardware from complete shutdown (mouse, keyboard, one or more power buttons, internet messages, etc).

Comment: I think the best option then is to replace the power button. I don't think it is possible to have the keyboard wake the PC from shutdown when there is no power going to it since it is plugged into the PC. You might be able to have a separate button on the table or something that acts as/"extends" the power button, or mess with wake on LAN/WLAN, so that is something I'd look into if you really want an easy way to wake the PC besides the power button located on the front of the PC.

Comment: @Sandsyr While I agree its a good idea to understand how to bypass the power button (or fix it), apparently that system has "AC recovery" mode which means the OP can set it to automatically power on when it detects AC.  Turning this on means the OP can always get their computer (re)booted by turning the power off and on at the wall/disconnecting + reconnecting the power cable.